# How to drag and drop an item from listview to treeview

Tags: c#, listview, treeview, drag-and-drop

Please provide some code example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I once blogged this exact topic:

http://crazorsharp.blogspot.com/2009/03/winforms-drag-drop-simple-example-to.html